# Can't logout of passport js and delete cookies

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a sample node app in which I'm trying to sign-up log-in and log-out users using passport js. I can successfully login and signup users, but when I try to logout users in my terminal I only get the console.log of my deserialize function and it doesn't affect cookies in my browser and also won't log out users since I can retrieve req.user after calling logout function. Here's my passport and express setup, serialize and deserialize function and also my logout,signup and sigin function:

```
//middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge:60*60*1000}//1hour
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));
 app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}));
app.use(cookieParser("secret"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    console.log("serializing user");
    cb(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findById(id).then((err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("id: " + id);
        console.log("userid: " + user);
        const userInformation = {
            username: user.email,
        };
        cb(err, user);
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err)});
});

passport.use(
    new localStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
        try{
            const user = await User.findOne({username: username});
            if(!user) {
                console.log("no user");
                return done(null, false);
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(result === true) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });
        } catch(err){
            console.log("err inside localStrategy: " + err);
            throw err;

        }
    }) 
);

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log("inside login");

    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
        console.log("inside authenticate, user: " + user);
        if(err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
            throw err;
        }
        if(!user) {
            console.log("No user");
            res.status(400);
            res.send("No user exists");
        }
        else {
            console.log("inside else");
            req.logIn(user, (err) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log("req.user: " + req.user);
                console.log("successfully authenticated");
                res.status(200).json({message: "successfully authenticated here"});
            });
        }
    })(req, res);
});

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        console.log("username: " + req.body.username);
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
        if(existingUser) {
            console.log("duplicate user");
            return res.status(400).json({message: "User already exists"});
        }
        console.log("password to be hashed: " + req.body.password);
        //hash password
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt)=>
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt,
                (err, hash) =>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.save()
                    .then((value)=> {
                        console.log("value: " + value);
                        console.log("registered: " + newUser.username);
                        return res.status(200).json({message: "User successfully registered"});
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }
            )
        );
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("error registering: " + err);
        res.status(500).json({message: "Internal srever error"});
    }
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("error: " + err);
            res.status(500).json({message: "Error destroying session"});
        } else {
            console.log("destroying session");
            res.clearCookie('mcookie');
            res.status(200).json({message: "Logged out successfully"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `req.logout` function without a callback gives me errors. Does this happens at your end? Is your website is being served from different server or the same one?

Comment: Thanks @deepanshu, no it doesn't give me any errors, it logs my deserialize function

Comment: What version of passport package are you using?

Comment: thanks @deepanshu, I have these in my package.json: passport: 0.6.0 , passport-local:1.0.0 , passport-local-mongoose:8.0.0

Comment: Can you try removing and readding passport package `npm remove passort --save-dev` `npm i passport --save-dev`

Comment: Hey @deepanshu, thanks again, did it but still can't logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `passport.deserializeUser` function.

OP said in their description, that it logs `deserializeUser` function and nothing changes. So it seems control flow of the program never moves beyond `deserializeUser` function. And if we look in browser's network console, it logs `500 Internal Server error`.

Moreover OP also said that the `req.logout` function without a callback, never gave errors on their end. And it is supposed to fail as this function, as of now (version 0.6.0), [requires a callback](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/logout/). So this also raised some eyebrows.

### Solution

Reading the code, it seems, the error is in the `then` part of `findById` function:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findById(id).then((err, user) => { //<== here
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("id: " + id);
        console.log("userid: " + user);
        const userInformation = {
            username: user.email,
        };
        cb(err, user);
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err)});
```

It seems you have interchanged those arguments.
So the solution is to just simply interchange those arguments.

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user,err) => { //now correct
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("id: " + id);
        console.log("userid: " + user);
        const userInformation = {
            username: user.email,
        };
        cb(err, user);
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err)});
});
```

So now the program should run fine and it should call your `req.logout` function. And that should give errors as you are not passing callback to the function.

Hope this helps! Ask if you need clarification.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton man. It seems the problem was the thing you mentioned. I can now logout and also check if req.user returns a value when logged in and out. 
I had to change logout function like the passport doc with a callback function though. The only thing that is not clear is I use req.session.destroy and also res.clearcookie but still there's a cookie in console>Application in chrome after I call them in my req.logout function. would also appreciate if you have any idea on this. Thanks again

Comment: @m0j1 To clear cookie, do this: `res.clearCookie("connect.sid")`